# git clone Fatal: out of memory Malloc Failed/ fatal: index-pack failed

Tags: git

Hello Everyone I'm having trouble using git clone. It has been working until lately when I tried to clone a larger repository I am getting the error message

```
Fatal: out of memory Malloc Failed
Fatal: index-pack failed
```

I have been searching all day for an answer so any help would be appreciated

(I am using Kali Linux 1.0.9 ARM on my Raspberry Pi model B+ if that is any help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since real RAM memory is rare on a raspberry pi, you could only increase your swap memory in order to increase the available virtual memory. However, accessing swap memory is much slower than real memory, meaning the process will take a long time to finish - but it should at least finish without an error.

Follow these steps to create and activate additional swap memory (1GB):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=swapfile bs=1024 count=$((1024*1000))
mkswap swapfile
swapon swapfile
```

Run the above commands as root.

Now try to run git clone again.

Comment: This did not work for me, albeit on a Virtual Machine and not an rpi.

Comment: I was able to turn on swap, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: You mean your git clone command needs more than 1.25G memory?

Comment: Apparently so. I added 2GiB swap partition, and even though the malloc call was 1.6G, 2G wasn't enough.

Comment: bs=1024 might not be enough. I used 2048... 2048*1000 with success after first trying just adding 1GB.